# How do I parse a JSON string where the objects are wrapped in another json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

I have an oddly formatted JSON string that looks like this and I'm trying to access the properties but not sure how to because of how its a bunch of json arrays within objects.

This stringified value of the variable data

```
  console.debug(JSON.stringify(data));
```

looks like this

```
[
{
    "note": [
        {
            "type": "2",
            "cid": "36",
            "icon": "cbb4153684de41ca61c0acc7124613b3.png",
            "created_at": "1359163643"
        }
    ],
    "count": 1
}
]
```

For example if I want the count int i tried

```
 var count = parseInt(data.count);
```

But that just results in NaN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data[0].count`

Just like a normal array.